# How do I slice a Multindex timeseries dataframe on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to slice a dataframe created by this code

```
data = pd.read_csv(("/user_home/w_hugopires/dados/dados_meteo.csv"),names=['POM','DTM','RNF','WET','HMD','TMP','DEW','INF'])
data['DTM'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DTM'], coerce = True)
data.set_index(['POM', 'DTM'], inplace=True)
```

First, I have to create a Multindex since there are DTM (timestamps) repeated between several POM (automatic weather stations).

The result is

```
                                RNF WET HMD TMP DEW INF
POM         DTM                     
QuintaVilar 2011-11-01 00:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
            2011-11-01 00:15:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
            2011-11-01 00:30:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
            2011-11-01 00:45:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
            2011-11-01 01:00:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Then I use the following code to create a slice of the dataframe

```
intervalo = data[['TMP','RNF']].ix[pom1][start_year + start_month + start_day : final_year + final_month + final_day]
```

And the result is

```
    TMP RNF
DTM     
2013-04-01 00:12:00  12.5    0
2013-04-01 00:27:00  12.1    0
2013-04-01 00:42:00  12.1    0
2013-04-01 00:57:00  11.7    0
2013-04-01 01:12:00  11.7    0
```

How can I slice with multiple POM's and how can I slice with multiple time intervals (eg every April of every year)?

Thank you

Hugo

Comment: Some tips to getter more response: provide a reproducible toy example (so some code to make a similar dataframe we can run to try out solutions) and try to clearly state the question (one question per post and eg show the desired output)

Comment: What can I say? 59 is not 7961. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example dataframe:

```
In [4]: data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((15,3)), columns=['RNF', 'WET', 'HMD'])            
   ...: data['DTM'] = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=5, freq='D').tolist()*3
   ...: data['POM'] = ['station1']*5 + ['station2']*5 + ['station3']*5
   ...: data = data.set_index(['POM', 'DTM'])


In [5]: data
Out[5]: 
                     RNF  WET  HMD
POM      DTM                      
station1 2012-01-01    0    0    0
         2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-03    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
         2012-01-05    0    0    0
station2 2012-01-01    0    0    0
         2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-03    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
         2012-01-05    0    0    0
station3 2012-01-01    0    0    0
         2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-03    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
         2012-01-05    0    0    0
```

**1. How to slice with multiple POMs?**

To just slice the first level, you can provide a list (eg `data.loc[['station1', 'station2']]`) or just slice (eg `data.loc['station1':'station3']`), but I suppose you mean how to slice the second level when having such a selection of multiple elements in the first level?

With the new multi-indexing functionality in version 0.14 (see [whatsnew docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers)), you can do this easily by just slicing the second level:

```
In [8]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [9]: data.loc[idx[['station1', 'station2'], '2012-01-02':'2012-01-04'], :]
Out[9]: 
                     RNF  WET  HMD
POM      DTM                      
station1 2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-03    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
station2 2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-03    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
```

This is equivalent to

```
data.loc[(['station1', 'station2'], slice('2012-01-02','2012-01-04')), :]
```

but `pd.IndexSlice` is provided as a way to not need to do the `slice(...)`

If you **don't have pandas version 0.14**, another way to do this is unstacking the dataframe (shifting the 'stations' index level to the columns):

```
In [12]: data2 = data.unstack(level=0).reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

In [13]: data2
Out[13]: 
POM         station1        station2        station3          
            RNF  WET  HMD   RNF  WET  HMD   RNF  WET  HMD
DTM                                                              
2012-01-01  0    0    0     0    0    0     0    0    0
2012-01-02  0    0    0     0    0    0     0    0    0
2012-01-03  0    0    0     0    0    0     0    0    0
2012-01-04  0    0    0     0    0    0     0    0    0
2012-01-05  0    0    0     0    0    0     0    0    0
```

and then you can easily slice on the rows:

```
data2['2012-01-02':'2012-01-04']
```

If you want it back in the origal form, you have to `stack` it back (the `reorder_levels` is needed because of `stack` inserts the 'stations' after the existing row index, while we want it as the first level of the row index):

```
data2['2012-01-02':'2012-01-04'].stack(0).reorder_levels([1,0], axis=0).sort_index(axis=0)
```

**2. How can I slice with multiple time intervals (eg every April of every year)?**

You can eg do this with boolean indexing. With an example to get day 2 and 4:

```
In [22]: time_index = data.index.get_level_values(1)

In [23]: selection = (time_index.day == 2) | (time_index.day == 4)

In [24]: data[selection]
Out[24]: 
                     RNF  WET  HMD
POM      DTM                      
station1 2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
station2 2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
station3 2012-01-02    0    0    0
         2012-01-04    0    0    0
```

In your case (eg to get every April of each year), this would be `data[time_index.month == 4]`.

To combine this with multiple selection of the first level (the stations) is more difficult in this case, but you can eg do this after this boolean indexing), or you can do it on the 'unstacked' dataframe (see the example above with `data2`).

---

Something else you may want to consider. Depending on your application, I personally think it can be more convenient to store the different stations in your columns index instead of the rows (so having a column multi-index), as shown with `data2`.

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for your time. Second, do I need 0.14? I am using Wakari and waiting for the upgrade. Third how do I "multislice" both levels, eg. every April of 2 Stations?

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need 0.14, as I also provided a solution for that can be used with older versions. And I will update my answer for your second question.

Comment: Added an answer to your second question, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Está óptimo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: data2 = data.unstack(level=0).reorder_levels([1,0],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1) gets the error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I guess it's because of the datetime

Comment: Do you also have duplicate datetime values within the values for one station? (this could indeed trigger this warning, as you cannot use unstack with duplicate entries) If so, is this needed? (you can always check with `data.index.get_duplicates()
`)

Comment: [('Armamar3', Timestamp('2010-05-09 11:30:00', tz=None))]. That's the problem. Is there a way to remove it?. I am trying data.drop(data.index[['POM']=='Armamar3']) but it doesn't work

Comment: You can feed that label (the tuple in this case (multi-index)) to drop: `data.drop(('Armamar3', pd.Timestamp('2010-05-09 11:30:00', tz=None)))
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55288/discussion-between-hugo-and-joris).